# Modify page behaviour in a cookbook .sty file to manage complex recipes

Tags: formatting, positioning, templates, package-writing, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to edit a .sty file for the typesetting of recipe books. It's a modification by Alexis Flesch of *cookybooky*:

[link to the full package (with output)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93894849/livre_recettes.tar.gz)

The problem is that the code is written to organize page content by minipages and if a recipe has an huge number of steps, the result is like this:

[image: Too long recipe]

I'd like to edit the .sty file in a way that permits to manually add a new page if the preparation steps are too much: the new page should have only the remaining preparation steps but at a full-page width, with the same style of the previous steps and maybe another image at the end of the recipe. It shouldn't have any clock symbol, recipe number or something else.

The question is: how can I do this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Most times, it's not necessary to edit the `.sty` file directly. The example in the `.tar` file does not compile, since `multind.sty` isn't available for me. `multind` is an **ooooooooooooooooooooooold` package, designed for `latex2.09`, apparently. The `imakeidx` package can be used for this

Comment: Thank you! So I could do it directly in my .tex file? How?

Comment: Hm, I have to dig into that `.sty` first -- It's very ... French ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer
You can get multind.sty from CTAN: copy it in your texmflocal styles folder (for texlive, C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\base) and then simply run command "texhash" from terminal

Comment: No, I don't install such an old, outdated package. It works without as well.

Comment: Well, you certainly are more into this than me. Even an outdated package is quite new for me :)

Comment: The whole package seems to consist of a bunch of minipages -- I hate minipages ;-) The whole thing should be a breakable box, not in a minipage.

Comment: Better to rewrite the entire package? I'm not sure if I'll be able to keep that beautiful style while doing this...

Comment: I've got an idea.. give me some minutes

Comment: Actually, it's perhaps easier to rewrite ;-)

Comment: Am I asking too much if I ask you a sample code as a template/guideline to rewrite the full package? :)

Comment: Not really, but at the moment, I can't provide a quick solution

Comment: If you'll have some spare time to give me the beginning of the solution, it'll be a priceless hint :)

Comment: Better, if you have any guide or similar to make/edit `.sty` files or to make new Latex classes, it would be the best!

Comment: I'll try, but the minipages should be replaced with boxes from `tcolorbox` (with white background etc.) those boxes are breakable and can be placed nicely using the `tcbraster` feature.

Comment: I went through some recipe books and observed a variety of different styles.  All of them could have been implemented using latex, but each would have taken a completely different approach.

Comment: The `flowfram` and `tcolorbox` packages seem both very good choices to make a good style for a recipes book, I'm going to try them and see what I get! Thank you for your precious hints!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples from different recipe books.  Perhaps this will give you some ideas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,left=.6in,right=.6in,
top=.75in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\pagestyle{empty}
\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node (title) [below=5pt,color=IndianRed] at(current page.north) {\Huge\textsf{\pagehead}};
  \node[draw=IndianRed,rounded corners=.2in,minimum width=5in,minimum height=7.2in]
    at (current page.center) {};
  \node (foot)[above=.3in,fill=Brown,minimum width=5in] at (current page.south) {\strut};
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \node[below,fill=Brown,text=white,minimum width=5in] at (title.south)
      {\small\phantom{SPEEDS IN PARENTHESIS REFER TO 10-SPEED MOTOR BASE}};
    \node[left,fill=white,text=Brown] at (foot.east) {\Huge\textsf{\thepage}};
  \else
    \node[below,fill=Brown,text=white,minimum width=5in] at (title.south)
      {\small SPEEDS IN PARENTHESIS REFER TO 10-SPEED MOTOR BASE};
    \node[right,fill=white,text=Brown] at (foot.west) {\Huge\textsf{\thepage}};
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\ingredientitem}[1]% #1 = number (math mode)
 {\ifvmode\else\par\fi\leavevmode
  \llap{$#1$\hspace{\itemsep}}}

\newcommand{\altitem}{\ifvmode\else\par\fi\leavevmode
  \hspace*{-\leftskip}}

\NewEnviron{ingredients}
 {\footnotesize\bfseries
  \let\item=\ingredientitem
  \begin{minipage}[b]{3.75in}\begin{multicols}{2}%
  \raggedright
  \leftskip=.25in
  \BODY
  \end{multicols}\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\flushtext}[1]% #1 = text to be flush right
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}\hspace{-\wd0}\null\hfill\box0
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\color{Brown}\small
\parskip=4pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\parindent=0pt
\def\pagehead{BREADS}
\centerline{\textsf{\Large\color{IndianRed}OLD-FASHIONED BANANA BREAD}}

\tikz{\node[black,draw,text width=.3in,inner sep=.1in,minimum height=.5in]{clip art};}
\begin{ingredients}
\item{\frac{1}{3}}cup (125 mL) shortning
\item{1}cup (250 mL) sugar
\item{2}eggs
\item{1}teaspoon (5mL) baking soda
\item{2}cups (500mL) all-purpose flour
\item{3}ripe bananas, sliced
\altitem % to add space, preventing column break at bakeing soda
\end{ingredients}

Preheat oven to $350^\circ$F ($180^\circ$C) .
Grease a $9'' \times 5'' \times 3''$ ($23 \times 13 \times 8$ cm) loaf pan.
Assemble mixer.
Put all ingredients into a large mixing bowl.
Mix on \#3 until thoroughly combined .
Pour into prepared pan.
Bake 1 hour and 10 minutes.
Cool slightly before removing from pan.
\flushtext{\textsf{Yield: 1 loaf}}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo 1]

---

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in,left=1in,right=.5in,
  top=.5in,bottom=.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@mystyle{\let\@oddhead=\relax
  \let\@evenhead=\relax
  \def\@oddfoot{\hfill\normalsize\thepage}%
  \def\@evenfoot{\normalsize\thepage\hfill}%
 }
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = text title
{\par
 \textbf{\LARGE\ #1}\newline
 \vbox{\baselineskip=0pt
   \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vspace{2pt}
   \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}
\par}

\newcommand{\ingredientitem}[1]% #1 = number (math mode)
 {\ifvmode\else\par\fi\leavevmode
  \llap{$#1$\hspace{\itemsep}}}

\newcommand{\altitem}{\ifvmode\else\par\fi\leavevmode
  \hspace*{-\leftskip}}

\newenvironment{ingredients}
 {\footnotesize\bfseries
  \let\item=\ingredientitem
  \raggedright\parskip=3pt
  \leftskip=.25in
 }{\par}

\setcolumnwidth{1.5in,2.5in}
\small

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=5pt
\raggedright

\mytitle{Pumpkin Squares}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{ingredients}
\item{1}package Duncan Hines Deluxe Spice Cake Mix
\item{\frac{1}{4}}cup plus 2 tablespoons Crisco Oil or Puritan Oil
\item{\frac{1}{2}}teaspoon salt
\item{\frac{1}{4}}teaspoon backing soda
\item{1}can (16 ounces) pumpkin
\item{2}cups whipped topping
\end{ingredients}
\switchcolumn%
Preheat oven to $350^\circ$.

Combine dry cake mix, oil, salt, and baking soda (mixture will be crumbly).
Press evenly in ungreased $13 \times 9 \times 2$-inch pan.

Bake at $350^\circ$ for 20 minutes or until crust is browned around edges.

Meanwhile, prepare pie filling recipe as directed on the can.
Pour over hot baked crust.

Bake at $350^\circ$ for 30 to 35 minutes or until center is firm.
Cool.
Spread whipped topping over cooled pumpkin filling.
Decorate with \textit{pecan halves}, if desired.
Store in refrigerator.

\hfill\textit{12 to 16 servings}

Note: If desired, for topping use dollop of sweetened whipped cream,
or scoop of vanilla ice cream and decorate with shaved chocolate.

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped demo]

Comment: Thank you!!!! These are very good inputs too, in the weekend I'll try to make a dedicated style