# A problem of counters, timing and etoolbox

Tags: counters, etoolbox

I am attempting a format for recipes. For *input,* each step of the method is accompanied by the ingredients for that step. The *output* places all of the ingredients together, and all of the steps of the method together, in what is commonly termed the “standard” format. Numbers are attached to the method steps that match the numbers for the ingredients, enabling a convenient correspondence between the two. I have tried various incantations involving `\xdef` and `\xappto` but seem to be missing an important piece of the puzzle. There is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161187/a-problem-with-counters) but it uses `collect.sty` and I don't know how to apply that here. **Clarification:** I don't mean to imply that I want to use `collect.sty` here, but that I don't know that solution applies to this problem.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xparse,etoolbox}

\newcounter{stepnum}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \NewDocumentCommand{\ingrline}{u{ }u{ }u{~}}{% #1=measure; #2=unit; #3=ingr. name
        \xappto{\ingrbody}{\noexpand\ing{#1}{#2}{#3}}~
    }%
    \def\methline#1~{% Line of method text
        \xappto{\methbody}{\unexpanded{\mth{#1}}}~% 
    }%
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\NewDocumentCommand{\ing}{mmm}{% Format: #1=measure; #2=unit; #3=ingr. name
    \textbf{\xstepnum}:\ \textit{#1-#2}\ \emph{\textbf{#3}}\par%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mth}{m}{% Format: Line of method text
    \textbf{\xstepnum:\ }#1\par
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{recipe}{s O{} m}{% *=?; #2=keyval; #3=title
    \setcounter{stepnum}{0}%% stepnum attaches both to group of ingredients and each method step
    \gdef\ingrbody{}%
    \gdef\methbody{}%
}{%
    %% output \ingrbody and \methbody
    \ingrbody
    \par
    \methbody
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{step}{}{%
    \stepcounter{stepnum}
    \xdef\xstepnum{\thestepnum}
    %% Assemble ingredients
    \begingroup %% write ingredients to \ingrbody
        \offinterlineskip
        \obeylines
        \everypar={\ingrline}
}{%
    \endgroup %% End method
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\method}{}{%
    \endgroup %% end ingredients
    \begingroup %% begin method write method to \methbody
        \offinterlineskip
        \obeylines
        \everypar={\methline}
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{A test}
    \begin{step}% 1
        1 cup butter (should be ``1:'')
        ½ cup sugar (should be ``1:'')
        \method
        Beat butter and sugar together until fluffy. (should be 1:)
    \end{step}
    \begin{step}% 2
        2 cups flour
        1 tablespoon baking powder
        \method
        Add to the butter mixture and combine.
    \end{step}
\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

gives this output:

[image]

The final format will be very different. This is just an ***M***WE.

Comment: Counters are always global (count registers are local).

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301298/modify-page-behaviour-in-a-cookbook-sty-file-to-manage-complex-recipes

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think I was--at some level--aware of that, but I don't see how that applies to this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You globally assign to `\xstepnum` the value of the `stepnum` counter right after the environment `step` is called and after the counter has been increased. But the lines to be finally printed are put together (and the relvant macros expanded) only when the `recipe` environment is closed. At this time, however, `\xstepnum` holds the number of the last step. Therefore this number will be put in every entry or line.

Therefore, you need to pass the current step through the whole macro chain instead, up to the point where you put together the final lines, like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xparse,etoolbox}

\newcounter{stepnum}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \NewDocumentCommand{\ingrline}{mu{ }u{ }u{~}}{% #1=stepnum; #2=measure; #3=unit; #4=ingr. name
        \xappto{\ingrbody}{\ing{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}~
    }%
    \NewDocumentCommand{\methline}{mu{~}}{% #1=stepnum; #2 rest
        \xappto{\methbody}{\mth{#1}{#2}}~% 
    }%
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\NewDocumentCommand{\ing}{mmmm}{% Format: #1=stepnum; #2=measure; #3=unit; #4=ingr. name
    \textbf{#1}:\ \textit{#2~#3}\ \emph{\textbf{#4}}\par%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mth}{mm}{% Format: #1=stepnum, #2=Line of method text
    \textbf{#1:\ }#2\par
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{recipe}{s O{} m}{% *=?; #2=keyval; #3=title
    \setcounter{stepnum}{0} %% stepnum attaches both to group of ingredients and each method step
    \gdef\ingrbody{}%
    \gdef\methbody{}%
}{%
    %% output \ingrbody and \methbody
    \ingrbody
    \par
    \methbody
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{step}{}{%
    \stepcounter{stepnum}
    %% Assemble ingredients
    \begingroup %% write ingredients to \ingrbody
        \offinterlineskip
        \obeylines
        \everypar={\ingrline{\thestepnum}}
}{%
    \endgroup %% End method
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\method}{}{%
    \endgroup %% end ingredients
    \begingroup %% begin method write method to \methbody
        \offinterlineskip
        \obeylines
        \everypar={\methline{\thestepnum}}
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{A test}
    \begin{step}% 1
        1 cup butter (should be ``1:'')
        ½ cup sugar (should be ``1:'')
        \method
        Beat butter and sugar together until fluffy. (should be 1:)
    \end{step}
    \begin{step}% 2
        2 cups flour
        1 tablespoon baking powder
        \method
        Add to the butter mixture and combine.
    \end{step}
\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: In the definition of `\ing` I changed `\textit{#1-#2}` to `\textit{#1~#2}` since I believe that this is what you actually meant.

Comment: Ah. I could see what was happening, not how to fix it. *Fiat lux!*