# writing a menu in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, document-classes

I am trying to write a simple menu. I would like to insert aligned numbers on the left and want to fit the following on one page, if possible should look more like a menu. many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt, 1p]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{gray}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{0.5em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}



\begin{document}
    %\tableofcontents
    \section{ANTIPASTI CRUDI}
    \noindent
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
    
    
\subsection{\centerline{Plateaux di crostacei e ostriche \texteuro 45}}

\subsection{\centerline{Crudo completo ‘Mariscos’ (carpacci, tartare, crostacei e ostrica) \texteuro 35}}

\subsection{\centerline{* Tartare di salmone ‘Oraking’ con sfoglia di mango e polvere di anice \texteuro 18}}

\subsection{\centerline{ * Tartare di tonno ‘Bluefin’ con zenzero rosa e germogli di pisello verde \texteuro 18 }}

\subsection{\centerline{ * Tartare di ricciola con uvetta jumbo e arancia candita \texteuro 18}}

\subsection{\centerline{ Tris di tartare (ricciola, salmone, tonno)  \texteuro 22}}


\section{Le NOSTRE CRUDITE}
%\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}
        
\subsection{\centerline{Gambero viola di Gallipoli  \texteuro 4 }}

\subsection{\centerline{Mazzancolla dell’Adriatico \texteuro 4 }}

\subsection{\centerline{Gambero rosso di Mazara del Vallo  \texteuro 5}}

    
\subsection{\centerline{Gambero rosso Carabineros imperiale  \texteuro 14 }}

\subsection{\centerline{Scampo dell’Adriatico  \texteuro  6}}

\subsection{\centerline{Scampo reale dell’Adriatico \texteuro 15}}

    
\subsection{\centerline{Ricci, tartufi, cozze pelose, scrigno di venere, s.q. \\ 
capasanta americana, cannelli gentili }}


\section{\color{orange} OSTRICHE}
%\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}



\subsection{\color{orange}{Fine David Herve -} \color{black}Charente-Maritime, Francia 3 cad. }

\subsection{\color{orange}{Special Pleiade Poget -} \color{black}Marennes Oléron, Francia 4 cad. }
    

\subsection{\color{orange}{Gillardeau -} \color{black} Marennes Oléron, Francia 5 cad}

\subsection{\color{orange}{La Regal Selection Or -} \color{black} Bannow Bay, Irlanda 6 cad. }


    
\subsection{ \texteuro }
\subsection{ \texteuro }
\subsection{ \texteuro }



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bit vague. Do you mean *vertically* aligned numbers? Then it will destroy the horizontal alignment you currently have. Would you accept some padding (with spaces or dots) inside a line, between the number and the description, and between the description and the price?

Comment: Yeah vertically aligned numbers for each item. But if not dots would be great too.

Comment: Maybe a `tabular` environment with a left aligned and a centered column? For the numbers you can use a counter.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301298/modify-page-behaviour-in-a-cookbook-sty-file-to-manage-complex-recipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit rudimentary, but is it going into the right direction? I'm not a fan of using `\subsection` for something isn't a subsection, so I removed its use. The dots are generated with `\dotfill`, you can replace it with `\hfill` if you just want spaces, or `\hrule` if you prefer a line.

I moved part of the code to a `onefood` to avoid tedious repetitions and facilitate customization once you know what you want exactly.

Again, this isn't a work of art, I'm no designer, see this as just a starting point.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{gray}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
\newcounter{food}
\setcounter{food}{1}

\newcommand{\onefood}[2]{%
\thefood\dotfill #1 \dotfill\texteuro #2%
\stepcounter{food}\\
}

\begin{document}
\section{ANTIPASTI CRUDI}
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}

\begin{center}
\onefood{Plateaux di crostacei e ostriche}{45}
\onefood{Crudo completo ‘Mariscos’ (carpacci, tartare, crostacei e ostrica)}{35}
\onefood{Tartare di salmone ‘Oraking’ con sfoglia di mango e polvere di anice}{18}
\onefood{Tartare di tonno ‘Bluefin’ con zenzero rosa e germogli di pisello verde}{18}
\onefood{Tartare di ricciola con uvetta jumbo e arancia candita}{18}
\onefood{Tris di tartare (ricciola, salmone, tonno)}{22}
\end{center}


\section{Le NOSTRE CRUDITE}
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}

\begin{center}
\onefood{Gambero viola di Gallipoli}{4}
\onefood{Mazzancolla dell’Adriatico}{4}
\onefood{Gambero rosso di Mazara del Vallo}{5}
\onefood{Gambero rosso Carabineros imperiale}{14}
\onefood{Scampo dell’Adriatico}{6}
\onefood{Scampo reale dell’Adriatico}{15}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Menu]

Comment: I would rather omit the dotfill on the left side. But this is my personal opinion.

Comment: I appriciate it, i will try to change the dots' color to white.

Comment: Replace `\dotfill` with `\hfill`, then. No need for dots if they're white.